# Android Java: Send array in array via http POST?

Tags: android, post, request

I have a problem with http POST request on android.

The main purpose is to send a "dictionary in dictionary" and in API it looks like

array('make_event'=>array(event_name'=>'Test event','event_start'=>'2012-12-01 10:00:00','event_end'=>'2012-12-02 10:00:00','host'=>10001001000,'is_global'=>0,'place_name'=>'Vasya\'s Appartments','place_id'=>666666666,'lat'=>49.00003,'long'=>54.30001,'invited'=>'135,1002541,21231,32321'))

and here is my realisation of request

```
List<BasicNameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
Bundle bndl = new Bundle();

bndl.putString("event_name","New Test Event");
bndl.putString("event_start", "2013-01-04 10:12:09");
bndl.putString("event_end", "2013-02-04 12:12:09");
bndl.putLong("host", 100003017925182L);
bndl.putInt("is_global", 1);
bndl.putString("place_name","Some PLace");
bndl.putString("place_id", "42cc7080f964a520e9251fe3");
bndl.putDouble("lat", 37.78573590563453);
bndl.putDouble("long", -122.40610713227913);
bndl.putString("invited","100000879281531");

String tmpStr = bndl.toString();

tmpStr = tmpStr.replace("Bundle", "");
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("make_event", tmpStr));

post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));



Log.v("My Post", "" + pairs.toString());

//HttpResponce
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

My task is to send a http POST and recieve a JSON response.

So my question is: Am I doing all right, or there is another way to send array in array via http POST??

---

Problem Resolved
Answer is at this question:
[Java Android: How to make complex POST requests to API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14169634/java-android-how-to-make-complex-post-requests-to-api)

Comment: you need to modify your backend, if php then use echo json_encode($yourphparray);

Comment: just convert your array to `JSON` format and send it to server as `String` parameter, and then parse the `JSONArray` in your server side