# Java Android: How to make complex POST requests to API?

Tags: android, post, request

**For example I such an API like:**

`array('make_event' = array('event_id' = "event id", 'start_date' = "some date", 'end_date' = "some else date"))`

I was trying to make it through Lists of NameValuePair, but I can't do it, because there is no constructor of `NameValuePair` for Objects.

The main problem is to pass "**Array of Arrays**" to `setEntity` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the soluton, if you need to make such a request without using JSON, it would look like this:

```
List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("make_event[event_id]", "My new Event"));
```

... and so on for each pair

then just

```
post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));
```

And all this code will generate standart POST request.

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to use nested `JSONArray`s; once you've created your complex array simple use `toString()` and insert the result into your `NameValuePair`.

Comment: nope, it doesn't work. When I try to pass JSONArray converted to string in BasicNameValuePair, service think it's one pair

Comment: Then all you have to do is create an array of `BasicNameValuePair`s, where the value on some of those pairs will be a `JSONObject` converted to a string.

Comment: Or you could write a function that loops through a `JSONArray` and creates a `BasicNameValuePair[]` array whose children's values are the string representations of the JSON values.